# BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter() Not returning null

Tags: android, bluetooth

This is my first post so if I do somethign dumb let me know please. This question may look similare to other posts but is more or less the opposite of everything that I've seen.

Things about the project:

- I'm working on an android 4.0 - 4.4 application.
- I'm Using Bluetooth
- I'm testing on a physical device (Eken Necnon) running android 4.2
- The device DOES NOT have bluetooth hardware

The problem I'm having is that when I try to get a Bluetooth Adapter using BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter() it should return null but it isn't.

```
BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();

if (mBluetoothAdapter == null) { // This does not ever return true.
    Log.w("Bluetooth", "Initializing bluetooth device failed: Bluetooth not supported.");
    return;
}

if (!mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
    mBluetoothAdapter.enable();
}

while (mBluetoothAdapter.getState() != BluetoothAdapter.STATE_ON) {
    try {
        Log.d(TAG, "Waiting for bluetooth adapter to turn on, taking nap.");
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This appears to be a device specific issue. Alternatively you can use `PackageManager` to find out whether bluetooth is supported.

```
PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();
boolean hasBluetooth = pm.hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_BLUETOOTH);
```

It is always a good practice to check where system feature is supported before accessing corresponding API.